# Set "OTHER_LDFLAGS" through command line with xcodebuild

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, ldflags

I have successfully compiled the project through `command line`.But i want set library(.a) file through command line .

It successfully build with below command
`/Users/Mahen/Documents/workspace/TestingApplication/Test/Test.xcodeproj -configuration` Debug build

Now I want set Linking .a file through command line.
I have try set "OTHER_LDFLAGS" option with 
-f`orce_load /Users/Mahen/Documents/workspace/Test.iOS/build/Debug-iphoneos/libTest.a -lstdc++`

But it couldn't load ,
Can you suggest the right way Linking .a files through the command line?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm not clear what your exact problem is, but hopefully one of these will help you or somebody else:

**To override an option** you go `xcodebuild "OPTIONNAME=newvalue"`

```
xcodebuild "OTHER_LDFLAGS= .... "
```

**Note** that this will override any other "OTHER_LDFLAGS" that you might have had in the actual xcode project.

**To link a library** `libNAME.a` you need to include in the linker flags `-lNAME` and also have the location of `libNAME.a` on the library search path `-Lpath/to/my/libraries`.

```
xcodebuild "OTHER_LDFLAGS=-Liphoneos -lTest"
```

**To force the library to link** even if there is no dependency (e.g. to include gtest cases) then you need to use `-force_load path/to/my/libraries/libNAME.a`

```
xcodebuild "OTHER_LDFLAGS=-force_load iphoneos/libTest.a"
```

Answer (score 1):

To set `OTHER_LDFLAGS` from the command-line you would do it like so *(note the placement of the quotation marks)*:

```
xcodebuild 
  -verbose 
  -configuration Debug build
  archive
  OTHER_LDFLAGS="-ObjC -weak_framework CoreMotion"
  #...
```