# Code pipeline library not found for -lGoogleToolboxForMac

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic3, azure-pipelines

I'm getting the library not found for -lGoogleToolboxForMac while running the xcodebuild command from commandline.

Most of the suggestions for this issue is resolving using xcode project. The pipeline calls the Cloud based MacOS agent and doesn't have any physical access to Mac system.

I tried this suggestion [command line option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20947969/set-other-ldflags-through-command-line-with-xcodebuild/47181980) but no luck. How do I include lGoogleToolboxForMac part of the build command?

```
2018-12-10T01:51:35.9852980Z 
2018-12-10T01:51:35.9853530Z ▸ Compiling main.m
2018-12-10T01:51:35.9854040Z ▸ Compiling UniversalAnalyticsPlugin.m
2018-12-10T01:51:35.9854790Z ▸ Compiling TouchID.m
2018-12-10T01:51:35.9855390Z ▸ Compiling TextResponseSerializer.m
2018-12-10T01:51:35.9856130Z ▸ Compiling TextRequestSerializer.m
2018-12-10T01:51:35.9856920Z ▸ Linking MyApp
2018-12-10T01:51:35.9857780Z ⚠️  ld: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hjgdkeujtihqvvhkvkijivuagzlb/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac'
2018-12-10T01:51:35.9858710Z ⚠️  ld: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hjgdkeujtihqvvhkvkijivuagzlb/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Protobuf'
2018-12-10T01:51:35.9859570Z ⚠️  ld: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hjgdkeujtihqvvhkvkijivuagzlb/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/nanopb'
2018-12-10T01:51:35.9860760Z ⚠️  ld: directory not found for option '-Liphoneos'
2018-12-10T01:51:35.9861030Z 
2018-12-10T01:51:35.9861860Z ❌  ld: library not found for -lGoogleToolboxForMac
2018-12-10T01:51:35.9861920Z 
2018-12-10T01:51:35.9862190Z 
2018-12-10T01:51:35.9862290Z 
2018-12-10T01:51:35.9862870Z ❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My code pipeline includes the below steps:

1. Install Apple Certificate
2. Install Mobile Provision file
3. Install Node JS
4. Install Ionic
5. Install Cordova
6. Install NPM
7. Install Pod
8. Ionic Cordova Platform Add ios
9. Ionic Cordova Build ios

What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation, but I have an extra step between 6 and 7 to install cocoapods.

Answer (score 0):

I had fixed a similar problem by running the command `pod install` in the `platforms/ios/` directory after iOS has been added.